# How to use context parameter of the filter() array with an arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arrow-functions

I filter out every person who falls between the ages of 13 and 19. It works with a normal callback function:

```js
let peoples = [
    {name: "Mohan",age: 65},
    {name: "Raj",age: 15},
    {name: "Sam",age: 13},
    {name: "Tamil",age: 3},
    {name: "selva",age: 25},
    {name: "siva",age: 16},
    {name: "Ram",age: 18},
]

let range = {
    lower: 13,
    upper : 16
}

let teenagers = peoples.filter(function(people){
    return ( people.age >= this.lower && people.age <= this.upper);
},range);
console.log(teenagers);
```

However, the arrow function it gives an empty array:

```js
let peoples = [
    {name: "Mohan",age: 65},
    {name: "Raj",age: 15},
    {name: "Sam",age: 13},
    {name: "Tamil",age: 3},
    {name: "selva",age: 25},
    {name: "siva",age: 16},
    {name: "Ram",age: 18},
]

let range = {
    lower: 13,
    upper : 16
}

let teenagers = peoples.filter((people) =>{
    return (
        people.age >= this.lower && 
        people.age <= this.upper
        );
},range);

console.log(teenagers);
```

How to access the context object with `this`?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20with%20arrow%20functions,that%20defined%20the%20arrow%20function.

Comment: instead just `return people.age >= range.lower && people.age <= range.upper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because lambda functions (arrow) get the context of where they're defined, in this case `Window`, which doesn't have `lower` or `upper` props. Just use `range.upper` and `range.lower` instead of `this` and should work just fine.